# Service to Activity communication

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to update the UI (Activity) after some action has been performed in the service. This is very simple example but it doesn't seem to work for me. What am I missing here?

ExampleService:

```
  public class ExampleService extends IntentService{
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        notifyActivity();
    }

    private void notifyActivity() {
        Intent broadcast = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
        sendBroadcast(broadcast);
    }
  }
```

ExampleActivity:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends ListActivity {
         private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send a broadcast to an anonymous dynamic receiver that way. You will need to define an action string in the `Intent` and use that action string in the `IntentFilter`.

You might consider using [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) for this scenario, for better performance. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Local) demonstrating this.

Comment: Is the LocalBroadcastManager available in the compatibility package? I can't find it in the v4 that I have downloaded.

Comment: In regards to the action string in the Intents, are there any rules - or I can put a 'example.action.string'?

Comment: @karruma: "Is the LocalBroadcastManager available in the compatibility package?" -- yes. "In regards to the action string in the Intents, are there any rules" -- for `LocalBroadcastManager`, use whatever you want. For "real" broadcasts, you want your string to be unique, so it is typically prefixed with your application's package.